# Serial Number Detection with openCV

Tags: c, opencv, video-streaming, video-processing, opencv3.0

I have a video with a serial number. Like in the picture. How I can with openCV detect the position of this patron. The only thing that I need is detect the location of this patron. Always this patron will have 12 numbers and will be white.

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dnpaP.jpg)

Comment: Whatever you do will have to distinguish the lettering "QATAR AIRWAYS" which also has 12 white characters.

Comment: I need detect the 12 numbers in the right corner of the picture, the number are from 0 to 9.

Comment: If the text is always white and displayed in the same position, then you probably don't need to use OpenCV. Just crop this section of the image, threshold it to obtain white text on a black background, and use OCR software such as tesseract to identify the characters.

Comment: @user3373406 you asked that you need to determine its position. Now you are telling us where it is. Suppose the Qatar shirt was nearby?

Comment: Sorry for the confutation. The patron always will be the same, 12 numbers but not the position. The position can be random. I need determine the box for this patron for remove it.

Comment: If the number is the same on every frame, find which pixels are white in several successive frames.

Comment: Good idea. But you can give me a example of how I can do that in openCV.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using [Morphological Transformations](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d9/d61/tutorial_py_morphological_ops.html#gsc.tab=0) you can find location of numbers.

try the code below (not a perfect code, it is just for instruction)

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Mat src=imread("dnpaP.jpg");
    Mat thresh = src.clone();

    dilate(thresh,thresh,Mat(),Point(-1,-1), 5);
    erode(thresh,thresh,Mat(),Point(-1,-1), 5);
    cvtColor(thresh, thresh, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    threshold(thresh, thresh, 200, 255, THRESH_BINARY);
    erode(thresh,thresh,Mat(),Point(-1,-1), 3);
    dilate(thresh,thresh,Mat(),Point(-1,-1), 3);

    vector<vector<Point> > contours;

    findContours(thresh.clone(), contours, RETR_LIST, CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

    for( size_t i = 0; i< contours.size(); i++ )
    {
        Rect boundingRect_ = boundingRect( contours[i] );
        if(boundingRect_.width > boundingRect_.height * 12)
        rectangle(src,boundingRect_,Scalar(0,0,255),2);
    }
    imshow("thresh",thresh);
    imshow("src",src);
    waitKey();
}
```

[image]
[image]